# Pass value of multiple fields to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass multiple field on to jquery to do an check for example, but i only get value of the changed field passed to jquery how can i pass both field to jquery

```
Enter some text: 
<input type="text" name="txt1" value="Hello" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
<input type="text" name="txt2" value="Hello" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">


<script>
function myFunction(txt1, txt2) {
  alert("The input value has changed. The new value is: " + txt1 + txt2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: is this a typo : function myFunction(txt1, text2)   which should be function myFunction(txt1, txt2)

Comment: Give each input a unique id, or both of them a common class, and look up the elements in the method.

Comment: @Satya it was typo here but correcting the typo was not the sollution

Comment: how do i lookup the elements @Taplar

Comment: Basic `$(selector)` logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason yours doesnt work is because of this `this` context, it refers to the item that has changed. You can access that from inside that input.

You can however access them in another way, e.g. `getElementsByName`:

```
function myFunction() {
    let text1 = document.getElementsByName('txt1')[0].value;
    let text2 = document.getElementsByName('txt2')[0].value;
    alert("The input value has changed. The new value is: " + txt1 + txt2);
}

<input type="text" name="txt1" value="Hello" onchange="myFunction()">
<input type="text" name="txt2" value="Hello" onchange="myFunction()">
```

I've now selected it via name. If you only intend to use it via javascript, I recommend dropping the `name` attribute and use `id` instead. You can then replace `getElementsByName('txt1')[0]` with `getElementsById('txt1')`, which is a little cleaner to read and is (slightly) faster.

---

If you want to step it up a notch: It's not standard practice to add eventhandlers right into the inputs, but to hook them on:

```
<input id="txt1" value="Hello" /> <!-- type=text is the default type, you can ommit it -->
document.getElementById('text1').onchange = myFunction;
```

Comment: jquery is useless here.

Comment: Myeah, though `$('#text1').val()` reads nice and easy. I do recommend vanilla JS here though, as that often is faster :)

Comment: I need jquery for the next step

Comment: Well, you don't *need* jquery :) It's just very convenient sometimes :) jquery is just some collection of JS functions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the reason why your code didn't work, you are trying to pass in a value of an undefined element. Remember that you are firing onchange event, and once you change one of the input fields the other remains the same not firing the onchange event. so to make sure you get the value of another input field only if one of the field is changed.

> Use document.querySelectorAll('classOfTheFields');

and loop through using **for** and get the values as done below.

```html
<input type="text" name="txt1" class="inner" value="Hello" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
        <input type="text" name="txt2" class="inner" value="Hello" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">

    <script>
    var allValue = [];
    function myFunction() {
      text = document.querySelectorAll('.inner');
      for (var I = 0;I<text.length;I++){
       allValue = text[I].value;
        console.log(text[I].value);
      }
    }
    </script>
```

***Hope this helps***